# How to use multiple "or" in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code below only prints "Remove Special Character". but if i leave only ("#"), it runs very well.

```
def name_character(word=input("Username: ")):
    if ("#") or ("$") or ("&") in word:
        return print ("Remove Special Character")
    if word == "":
        return print ("Enter Username")
    else: 
        return print (word)

(name_character())
```

Comment: `or` is a boolean operator, not the English grammar construct. You need to be explicit: `'#' in word or '$' in word or '&' in word`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just put the strings in a array:
` chars = ['#', '$', '&'] `

Comment: @ghovat: yes, the duplicate gives you more options. I was merely pointing out the reason why the OP's attempt did not work.

Comment: Also, do not use default values to a function parameter to ask the user for input. That `input()` call will be processed **just once**. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](//stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison is turning  somewhat like this

> if("#" or .....)

and # is returned at the first comparison.

Do it in multiple or comparison, it will work

```
def name_character(word=input("Username: ")):
    if (("#") in word )or (("$") in word ) or (("&") in word ) :
        return print ("Remove Special Character")
    if word == "":
        return print ("Enter Username")
    else: 
        return print (word)

(name_character())
```

Comment: Thanks Rathan. your suggestion worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> username = "foo#"
>>> any(x in username for x in "#&$")
True
>>> username = "bar"
>>> any(x in username for x in "#&$")
False
```